# C. Passing pointers to be modified causing segmentation faults

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I am making a decimal to binary converter in C for a class. I want to pass a char array to my function as well as the the decimal as an int.
ie void DtoB(int decimal, char *array);
DtoB will do the math and modify array to be the binary value. Ideally by giving it int values. Main() will just scanf(decimal), DtoB(decimal,array), and printf(array).

Here is what I have. This just returns a segmentation fault

```
1 #include <stdio.h>
2 #include <math.h>
3
4 void DecToBin(unsigned int, char *binary);
5
6 int main()
7 {
8         unsigned int dec;
9         char *binary[];
10         while(1) {
11                 scanf("%d", &dec);
12                 DecToBin(dec,*binary);
13                 printf("In binary is ");
14                 printf("%s\n",binary);
15         }
16 }
17 void DecToBin(unsigned int dec, char *binary)
18 {
19         int counter=0;
20         while(dec) {
21                 binary[counter]=dec%2;
22                 dec/=2;
23                 counter++;
24         }
25 }
```

I want it done like this since this seems like the best way to be able to do 32 bit integers, while keeping the array at the minimum size.
Sorry if I killed formatting. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `char *binary[33];` declares an *array-of-pointers* -- none of which are allocated. `DecToBin(dec,*binary)` is the same as `DecToBin(dec, binary[0])`.

Comment: As currently written, `char *binary[];` won't compile; you can't define an array in the body of a function without a non-zero size (GCC may permit a zero size, but that's a compiler extension).  You actually want `char binary[33];` and then pass `binary` (not `*binary)` to your function.

Comment: when writing/posting code, do no use tabs for indenting.  Because each wordprocessor/editor has the tab stops/tab widths set differently  Suggest using 4 spaces for each indent level as that is wide enough to be visible even with variable width fonts and still allows many levels of indenting across the page

Comment: this line: `DecToBin(dec,*binary);` is dereferencing the array/pointer `binary[]`  Suggest: `DecToBin(dec,binary);`.   This is because in C, an array name (in most instances) degrades to the address of the first byte of the array.

Comment: in general, the code should always check the returned value (not the parameter value) from `scanf()` to assure the operation was successful.  In this case, the returned value should be 1.

Comment: this line: `binary[counter]=dec%2;` has the problem that the resulting array `binary[]` will contain the binary digits [0|] is the reverse order.  I.E. the least significant bit will be first, rather than last AND the result will be left justified within the array.   Note: no space was ever allocated for the array, only for an array of pointers, so the code, when run will contain undefined behaviour (writing bytes to some random memory) and will lead to a seg fault event

Comment: nothing in the posted code is using anything from `math.h` so that header file should not be `#include`d

Comment: `dec` is declared as `unsigned int` so the scanf() format specifier needs to be `%u` rather than `%d`

Comment: the line: `binary[counter]= dec%2;` is placing 0x00 and/or 0x01 into the bytes of `binary[]` array what it should be placing is 0x30 and/or 0x31 which are the characters '0' and '1'.  Suggest: `binary[counter]= (char)((dec%2)+0x30);`

Answer (score 1):

```
char *binary[33]
```

binary is array of pointers. So each element in it is a pointer.

The segmentation fault is because you are not initializing your array and trying to use it.

You are dereferencing a pointer which is not pointing to any valid memory location.

You need to allocate memory to the members of the array before using them

Answer (score 1):

incorporating all the comments, incorporating error checking, etc. the posted code becomes :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>  // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE
#include <string.h>  // memset()


// prototypes
void DecToBin(unsigned int, char *binary);

int main()
{
        unsigned int dec;
        char binary[sizeof(int)*8 +1];


        while(1)
        {
                if( 1 != scanf("%u", &dec) )
                { // then scanf failed
                    perror( "scanf for decimal value failed" );
                    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
                }

                // implied else, scanf successful

                DecToBin(dec, binary);
                printf("In binary is ");
                printf("%s\n",binary);
        }
}


void DecToBin(unsigned int dec, char *binary)
{
        size_t counter= sizeof(int)*8;

        memset( binary, ' ', counter );
        binary[ counter ] = '\0'; // terminate string
        counter--;

        // do...while allows for dec being 0
        do
        {
                binary[counter]= (char)((dec%2)+ 0x30);
                dec /= 2;
                counter--;
        }  while(dec);
}
```

which still has the shortcoming that the user is left with a blank screen and a blinking cursor.  I.E. the code should be prompting the user, by requesting the input value.

Comment: You can use `CHAR_BIT` instead of `8`   (slightly more self-documenting)

Comment: in fact will be waiting for input, just provide input hit  return and also you can add some think like printf("Please provide inputs") in beginning  for while(1) {}, it will be useful know it is waiting for input